# Intermediate Jacobian for small resolution of a singular Fano threefold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, hodge-theory, fano-varieties

I am mainly interested in the nodal Gushel-Mukai threefold. Let $X$ be a Gushel-Mukai threefold with one node, then by page 21 of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.4724.pdf there is a short exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow J(X)\rightarrow J(\widetilde{X})\rightarrow 0,$$
where $\widetilde{X}$ is the normalization of $X$ and it is birational isomorphic to a Verra threefold $V$ and $J(V)\cong J(\widetilde{X})$. It is known that the dimension of $J(\widetilde{X})$ is $9$ and dimension of $J(X)$ is $10$.

Now, I consider a special one-nodal Gushel-Mukai threefold $X'$: one-nodal **maximally non-factorial** Gushel-Mukai threefold, whose definition is given in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.09081.pdf

It is shown that this kind of one-nodal GM threefold comes from a "bridge construction": we start with a quartic double solid $Y$, blowing up a general line $L$(we get $\hat{X}$), then we contract the strict transform of a line $L'\subset Y$ which is bisecant to $L$ to get the one-nodal maximally non-factorial GM threefold $X$. It is known that the contraction $\hat{X}\rightarrow X$ is a projective small resolution.

**My question** is what is the relation of $J(X)$ and $J(\hat{X})$????

By construction, $J(\hat{X})\cong J(Y)$, so they are both $10$-dimensional, $J(X)$ is also $10$-dimensional.

Comment: What definition of $J(X)$ for singular $X$ do you use?

Comment: @Sasha, here I take the definition to be the generalized intermediate Jacobian given by S.Zuker in his paper "Generalized Intermediate Jacobians and the theorem on normal functions". I think this definition coincides with the one given in Debarre-Iliev-Manivel for nodal Gushel-Mukai threefold, right?(I mean the what they called rank one degeneration of intermediate Jacobian).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use the limiting Hodge structure of the middle cohomology to define the intermediate Jacobian. Then the proof of Proposition A.16 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.09081.pdf identifies $J(X)$ with $J(\hat{X})$.

Comment: @Sasha, yes what you said is absolutely true, I think you mean the paper Proposition A.16 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.17213.pdf right? The paper you mentioned is the four-guy paper on classification of one-nodal maximally non-factorial index one prime Fano threefolds.

Comment: I think the extension sequence you start with only applies when $X$ is factorial. Otherwise the Jacobian is an abelian variety already, not a semi-abelian variety.

Comment: @user41650: Yes, I confused the paper, sorry.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder, thanks for explaining this matter, this is exactly something I am confused since in the paper of Debarre-Iliev-Manivel, they did not say this, maybe I overlooked some assumptions.